# How to change the root domain in of links with a certain class attribute on onmousedown event?

Tags: javascript, html

We have a large amount of webpages on our blog with links to a certain domain (domain1.com) to another domain (domain2.com).
To save stuff from changing it manually, we try this without changeing the link (href). 
The links can be identified throug their `class`, they do not have an `id`.

```
<a href="domain1.com/id/12345" class="ChangeDomain">Click Here</a>
<a href="/internal_url/" class="">Click Here</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementsByClassName("ChangeDomain").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("ChangeDomain").href="domain2.com"; 
    return false;
  };
</script>
```

There is another thing I dont know how to accomplish.
only the root domain changs and domain2.com needs to have the same path as domain1.com.
 The url *domain1.com/id/12345* becomes *domain2.com/id/12345*

Comment: Can you use jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use jquery, then all hrefs can be modified when the document is ready this way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.ChangeDomain').each(function(){ 
            var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href"); // Get current url
            var newUrl = oldUrl.replace("domain1.com", "domain2.com"); // replace domain
            $(this).attr("href", newUrl); // Set herf value
        });
    });
```

the idea is to find all hrefs when the document is ready, and replace the current domain with a new domain

if you really need to use mousedown, then change it to:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.ChangeDomain').mousedown(function(){ 
        var oldUrl = $(this).attr("href"); // Get current url
        var newUrl = oldUrl.replace("domain1.com", "domain2.com"); // replace domain
        $(this).attr("href", newUrl); // Set herf value
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding event with `onclick`, add with `addEventListener`. Use `replace` to replace word `domain1` with `domain2`.

```js
const alinks = document.querySelectorAll(".ChangeDomain");

alinks.forEach(a => {
    a.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const href = this.href;
        const newHref = href.replace('domain1', 'domain2');
        console.log(newHref);
    })
});
```

```html
  <a href="domain1.com/id/12345" class="ChangeDomain">Click Here</a>
  <a href="/internal_url/" class="">Click Here</a>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementsByClassName("ChangeDomain").onclick = function() {
    const preUrl = document.getElementsByClassName("ChangeDomain").href;
    const newUrl = preUrl.replace("domain1.com", "domain2.com");
    console.log(newUrl); 
    return false;
  };
</script>
```